# Why POS tagging algorithm tags `can't` as separate words?

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm using [Stanford Log-linear Part-Of-Speech Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) and here is the sample sentence that I tag:

> He can't do that

When tagged I get this result:

> He_PRP ca_MD n't_RB do_VB that_DT

As you can see, `can't` is split into two words, `ca` is marked as Modal (MD) and `n't` is marked as ADVERB (RB)?

I actually get the same result if I use `can not` separately: `can` is MD and `not` is RB, so is this way of breaking up is expected instead of say breaking like `can_MD` and `'t_RB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is not the perfect answer.
I think that the problem originates from the Tokenizer used in Stanford POS Tagger, not from the tagger itself. the Tokenizer (PTBTokenizer) can not handle apostrophe properly:
1- [Stanford PTBTokenizer token's split delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229780/992406).
 
2-  [Stanford coreNLP - split words ignoring apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14058399/992406).
As they mentioned here [Stanford Tokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml), the PTBTokenizer  will tokenizes the sentence :

> "Oh, no," she's saying, "our $400 blender can't handle something this
>   hard!"

to:

> ...... 
>  our
>  $ 
> 400 
> blender
>  **ca**
>  **n't**
>  handle
>  something

Try to find a suitable tokenization method and apply it to the tagger as following:

```
    import java.util.List;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.TaggedWord;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String model = "F:/code/stanford-postagger-2015-04-20/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger";  
            MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(model);
            List<HasWord> sent;
            sent = Sentence.toWordList("He", "can", "'t", "do", "that", ".");
            //sent = Sentence.toWordList("He", "can't", "do", "that", ".");
            List<TaggedWord> taggedSent = tagger.tagSentence(sent);
            for (TaggedWord tw : taggedSent) {
                 System.out.print(tw.word() + "=" +  tw.tag() + " , " );

            }

        }

}
```

output:

> He=PRP , can=MD , 't=VB , do=VB , that=DT , .=. ,

Comment: Thanks, I might consider this approach. But it produces different result than original one - marks `'t` as VB instead of `RB` - so maybe I'll stick to the original tokenization.

Comment: This isn't a problem but a choice. We choose to follow the Penn Treebank part of speech tag set and hence tokenization....