# Entity Mention Detection is not working properly with TokensRegex

Tags: stanford-nlp

entitymention doesn't seem to work. I followed similar approach mentioned here by adding `entitymentions` as one of the `annotators`

[How can I detect named entities that have more than 1 word using CoreNLP's RegexNER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100750/how-can-i-detect-named-entities-that-have-more-than-1-word-using-corenlps-regex)

Input : "Here is your 24 USD"

I have a TokensRegex:

```
{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ([{ner:"NUMBER"}] + [{word:"USD"}]), action: Annotate($0, ner, "NEW_MONEY"), result: "NEW_MONEY_RESULT" }
```

Init Pipeline:

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregex,entitymentions");
props.setProperty("tokensregex.rules", "basic_ner.rules");
```

I still got 2 CoreEntityMention instead of just 1.

Both of them have the same value for `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation` which is `NEW_MONEY`

but they have different  `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$EntityMentionIndexAnnotation`

which is `0` for `24`

`1` for `USD`

How can they be merged since they both have same entity tag annotation.

`3.9.2` version of stanford library is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that numbers have a normalized name entity tag.

Here is a rules file that will work:

```
# these Java classes will be used by the rules
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
normNER = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

# rule for recognizing company names
{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ([{ner:"NUMBER"}] [{word:"USD"}]), action: (Annotate($0, ner, "NEW_MONEY"), Annotate($0, normNER, "NEW_MONEY")), result: "NEW_MONEY" }
```

You should not add an extra `tokensregex` annotator and `entitymentions` annotator at the end.  The `ner` annotator will run these as sub-annotators.

Here is an example command:

```
java -Xmx10g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.tokensregex.rules new_money.rules -file new_money_example.txt -outputFormat text
```

More documentation here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html